# Looking for a movie about a gateway to hell

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I'm looking for a movie, not sure what year but probably early to late 2000's. Probably an American film.

My memory is vague but I think it was about humans fighting a monster, about human sized maybe a little smaller, that came through a gateway to hell/another dimension. I think it took place in modern day America.

The only thing I can remember clearly was that at the end one of the characters found the doorway and looked through it and the camera pans out to reveal hundreds of those same monsters all racing towards the gateway.

I've been looking for this title for ages and I cannot for the life of me remember anything else from it (I was young when I saw it). Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: The ending of Buffy? https://youtu.be/XBVm1Nl18fQ?t=4m42s

Comment: That could as well be an average Supernatural episode :-D

Comment: @Loki: all episodes of Supernatural are average.

Comment: It sounds like 'The Gate' (1987; Dir.: Tibor Takács)...?

Comment: Was it `Spawn` maybe?

Comment: @PaulDWaite I respectfully disagree sir!

Comment: Question is so vauge it can be "Constantine" as well.

Answer (score 2):

[*Alone in the Dark 2005*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0369226/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_69)? Sure it ends like that.

The scene in question:

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should include details of the movie to show how it matches the question.  Please read [answer].